# IoC Container(Prism Unity) interface resolve and C# interface limitation

Tags: c#, interface, inversion-of-control, prism, ioc-container

I have interface a question/confusion related to IoC purposes. Consider the following:

**ISite** - interface

**ImapSite**: ISite - non default constructor.

I register the interface with concrete imp using the container as following:

```
 _container.RegisterType<ISite, ImapSite>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(string), typeof(Account)));
```

And resolve it using:

```
_site = _container.Resolve<ISite>(new DependencyOverride[]
                                              {
                                                  new DependencyOverride<string>(host), 
                                                  new DependencyOverride<Account>(Account.FromAppConfig())
                                              });
```

I am now wondering if the this kinda beats the purpose of IoC because if I can't constrain what kind of constructor an ISite implementation will have, when ImapSite changes ctor signature I still have to change it everywhere in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are passing constructor arguments directly that defeats the purpose of IoC. You should rethink the design of your classes so that only *services* are injected. Maybe the arguments you're passing in should actually be arguments to individual methods on the class?

Comment: So all classes should have default ctor ?

Comment: @Zapacila: No, but they should only have "services" as constructor arguments: classes or interfaces that the IoC container already knows how to resolve and build without special runtime arguments. A class should only have a default constructor if it has no dependencies.